# Questions about video: should this question be re-opened

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

This question was closed by Robert Cartaino;
[Free fast and easy animation with sound](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/free-fast-and-easy-animation-with-sound). The reason: off-topic as per faq. correct as per the *current* FAQ states under 'what questions can i ask [on graphicdesign.stackexchange]:

> Graphic Design - Stack Exchange is for
>   professional graphic designers and
>   non-designers trying to do their own
>   graphic design.

However as many know the scope of the site has been up for discussion. The unoffical consensus for a new scope definition seems to be [Philip Regans answer here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/what-is-the-definition-of-design-for-a-design-stackexchange).

Re: video, philip proposes this split

on-topic:

> Digital media - (i.e., Flash, Video) [as it relates to 2D design]

off-topic:

> Technical questions related to Video editing software

The question under discussion asks for a 'what-software-should-i-use' suggestion, it isn't really a 'technical question' in the spirit of Philip's scope. It also received two answers quickly - a small indication that it fits the community.

Therefore i am re-opening the question (innocent till proven guilty). But i've started this thread to give Robert right of rebuttal. I also am happy if this stimulates discussion around what is/isn't acceptable in regards to video and video editing on this site.

---

As an aside: [can we please update the FAQ](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/topics-for-inclusion-in-the-faq).

Comment: you hold a community moderator diamond, so you can click edit on the faq page at the top!

Comment: I think it is high time we time we do something about that scope change. No one has come out against it, and what little objections we've seen they are more quibbles that need to be shaken out in process. I think we might have asked this before, but what is the best course of action to make the jump from "graphicdesign" to "design"?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, haven't noticed that before. Updated now

Comment: @Philip see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77918/how-will-the-area-51-discussion-proceed. we tag the discussion on area51 as [change-request]. done. Robert Cartaino is meant to review these questions and make a judgement. This is what we are waiting for and have been for about a month